# How applicationRunner is running in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, lambda

I'm bit confused to understand how spring is running Applicationrunner in below code ?

For example, see below code

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RsvpApplication {

    private static final String MEETUP_RSVPS_ENDPOINT = "ws://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RsvpApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner initializeConnection(
            RsvpsWebSocketHandler rsvpsWebSocketHandler) {
        return args -> {
            WebSocketClient rsvpsSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();

            rsvpsSocketClient.doHandshake(
                    rsvpsWebSocketHandler, MEETUP_RSVPS_ENDPOINT);           
        };
    }
}
```

In above snippet, `initializeConnection` is a method which returns `ApplicationRunner`, that's what it look like. But `rsvpsSocketClient.doHandshake` dont return anything. `RsvpsWebSocketHandler` is another component in code and its being used in `initializeConnection`.

Doubts:

1. Does spring initlialize everything before it calls `ApplicationRunner` ? Because it is using RsvpsWebSocketHandler and it has to be `on` before it get used.
2. Does spring looks for all methods which returns `ApplicationRunner` beans ? and then initialize them.
3. Majore doubt is, how `ApplicationRunner` could be return type of  `initializeConnection` method even though its not even returning anything like that. I know its mixed with labmda expression, but can anyone please share how `initializeConnection` makes sense even its not even returning what's specified, which is `ApplicationRunner` ?

Comment: *its not even returning anything like that* Can you explain in your own words how lambda expressions work?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-, In code, args is the parameter for run method of ApplicationRunner interface. but no where seems to be returning ApplicationRunner type from initializeConnection method. I hope I made clear

Comment: It's returning it where it says `return`. Everything following that is the lambda.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-, so you mean return is returning anonymous class implementing ApplicationRunner interface ?

Comment: Essentially, yes.

Comment: And do spring checks which method returning ApplicationRunner, then call it accordingly ?